# How to get coverage result for system testing using emma or similar tools!

Tags: java, emma

Is there any way to get system tests coverage results for a system involving two or more web applications deployed in single app server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did similar thing with cobertura and jboss. You should just 'instrument' all necessary classes, after that it doesn't matter how many modules you have deployed. Datafile will be somewhere around the server, perhaps in the 'bin' directory.

**edit**
Here they have section about web applications. Can't help you with emma, though.
http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: Thanks for it. I 'll wait if there is any emma help or otherwise 'll switch to this :)